# Backbone JS and Ruby on Rails new issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, backbone.js

Okay, so we've pushed live our first Backbone JS app and now we have new issue.
Apparently when I initially load models for comments and reviews, they have "created_at" attributes that contain time stamp of when they were added. When I edit a comment and then do model.sync(), it passes "created_at" back to the server. Now RoR app trips out about it, and as our Rails dev is telling me, I can't at no circumstance pass "created_at" back to the server and that it's calculated for display only.

Now something has to give. Either I have to hack Backbone and delete some attributes before sync() or something has to be done on Rails side.

What is your suggestion for the soluton?

And in any case, what can be done to NOT pass some attributes during model.sync()? I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: There should be no problem passing `created_at` back to the server, provided your Rails app is properly written and secured. Your Rails dev is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add to your model:

```
attr_protected :created_at, :updated_at
```

Comment: Thanks. Had an argument with the Rails dev re. this. He said this prevents him from manually overriding created_at from command line, so no way he would use this. Alright. I end up removing "created_at" before sync. In any case, it's passed with response. So it works.

Comment: When you make created_at protected with attr_protected, it disallows mass assignment like in user.update_attributes(params[:user]) ; however, you can still do user.created_at = some_value

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this exact problem with trying to post to immutable properties. The problem with Backbone models is that by default, they post all or nothing. But you can do partial updates. To deal with that, I created a Backbone.Model descendant, and overrode the model.save like so:

```js
    save : function(key, value, options) {
        var attributes, opts;

        //Need to use the same conditional that Backbone is using
        //in its default save so that attributes and options
        //are properly passed on to the prototype
        if (_.isObject(key) || key == null) {
            attributes = key;
            opts = value;
        } else {
            attributes = {};
            attributes[key] = value;
            opts = options;
        }

        //Now check to see if a partial update was requested
        //If so, then copy the passed attributes into options.data.
        //This will be passed through to Backbone.sync. When sync
        //sees that there's an options.data member, it'll use it instead of
        //the standard attributes hash.
        if (opts && opts.partialUpdate) {
            opts["data"] = JSON.stringify(attributes);
            opts["contentType"] = "application/json";
        }

        //Finally, make a call to the default save now that we've
        //got all the details worked out.
        return Backbone.Model.prototype.save.call(this, attributes, opts);
    }
```

This allows me to selectively post the attributes that I want to the backend like so:

```js
//from the view - the GET may have delivered 20 fields to me, but I'm only interested
//in posting the two fields.
this.model.save({
    field1 : field1Value,
    field2 : field2Value
},{
       partialUpdate : true
});
```

Can't tell you how this has made my life so much easier! Now given that, some might ask why not just pass the changedAttributes() JSON? The reason is because in some instances, the changed attributes are only meant for the client side, and specifically to elicit changes to views that also use that model.

In any case, try this out...

Comment: Thanks. But it looks like too much of a hack to the Backbone source. I end up removing "created_at" before sync -- in any case, it's passed with response and once synced, it contains the original created_at attribute.

Comment: But there's actually no messing with the Backbone source. It's a simple override of the save. Oh well...